# Use Powershell to query the tags on a Cloud Formation Stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

Is there a way to query the Cloud Formation Stack tags using Powershell?

Comment: Please be more spesific

Comment: I'm not sure how to be more specific. I know how to talk to AWS from powershell to query general stack information (Get-CFNStack) but cannot find a way to get a list of the tags shown in the AWS web console against a CF stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to take a guess at what you're asking for.  My interpretation is that you want to find out what tags are associate to a particular cloud formation stack

You can do this using the [`describe-stacks`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/describe-stacks.html) command that is shipped with the AWS CLI.  You can use the AWS CLI from within Powershell so it should meet your requirements.

Assuming you have a CloudFormation stack name you can use this (I've just ripped this from the documentation):

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name myteststack
```

If you want to return just the tags you can query the output (untested):

```
aws cloudformation describe-stacks --stack-name myteststack --query 'Stacks[*].Tags[*]'
```